# Change Mouse pointer for block selection in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, text-editor

How to change mouse pointer in eclipse block selection mode. It is a great feature but I am accustomed to dark theme and the pointer is barely visible.

I searched through Window → Preferences with any good results. I'm using kubuntu 15.04 with KDE plasma 5.2.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Eclipse is using system pointers. Working solution for my problem is edit system "crosshair" pointer. I found this option in KDE Plasma under:

```
System Settings → Workspace Appearance → Cursor Theme
```